# Setting X-RequestDigest from html page

Tags: rest, request-digest

I have html page in an app, I want to submit data to sharepoint using REST, so I don't have access to `$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").` How do I get the request digest from my html page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are situations/scenarios where the request digest is not available, for instance when you are developing a single page app. So in this case, it's your app code's responsibility to retrieve the value and refresh it. Please see this blog post:

http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-how-to-refresh-the-request-digest-value-in-javascript